# Postgres - how to add foreign key nullable constraint for two different columns coming from diff tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have three tables 1. Account 2. dept and 3. managers
In the managers table I need to add both account key and dept key as foreign key but one will null and other will have value, means if inserted account manager then dept key will null and account key will have value. how to add constraint in postgres

Comment: Add two foreign keys and a check constraint that guarantees your condition.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oEOoKy50)

```
create table account(id serial primary key);
insert into account values (default);

create table dept(id serial primary key);
insert into dept values (default);

create table manager(
  id serial primary key,
  account_id int references account(id),
  dept_id int references dept(id) );
```

---

### One `null`, one `not null`

If you always want exactly one of those foreign keys to be `null` and the other `not null`, you can use a [`XOR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). It won't allow both to have a value, and it will also not allow a row where they are both `null`:

```
alter table manager add constraint dept_xor_account
  check( (account_id is null) != (dept_id is null) );
```

There's a [XOR `#` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html#FUNCTIONS-BIT-STRING-OP-TABLE), but only for type `bit`, so it's not really worth all the casting:

```
alter table manager add constraint dept_xor_account
  check(((account_id is null)::int::bit # (dept_id is null)::int::bit)::int::bool);
```

You can also count the number of non-nulls

```
alter table manager add constraint dept_xor_account
  check( 1=num_nonnulls(account_id,dept_id) );
```

```
insert into manager values(default,1,null);--works fine
insert into manager values(default,null,1);--works fine

insert into manager values(default,1,1);--can't have both links
```

> ```
> ERROR:  new row for relation "manager" violates check constraint "dept_xor_account"
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, 1, 1).
> ```

```
insert into manager values(default,null,null);--can't have neither link
```

> ```
> ERROR:  new row for relation "manager" violates check constraint "dept_xor_account"
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, null, null).
> ```

---

### At most one not `null`

If you allow *at most one* to be not `null` (one or both can be `null`), a regular `OR` will suffice. That makes sense if you want to be able to create a manager before they can have an account or department assigned, or to hold manager records even if the account or deparment was taken away from them and assigned elsewhere:

```
alter table manager add constraint dept_or_account_or_neither
  check(account_id is null OR dept_id is null);

insert into manager values(default,1,null);--works fine
insert into manager values(default,null,1);--works fine
insert into manager values(default,null,null);--works fine, CAN have neither link

insert into manager values(default,1,1);--still can't have both links
```

> ```
> ERROR:  new row for relation "manager" violates check constraint "dept_or_account_or_neither"
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (8, 1, 1).
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oEOoKy50)

Answer (score -1):

Your description indicates yo are not looking for *at most 1 null*, but instead looking for **exactly 1 null**. You determine this with the [num_nulls() function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) incorporated into a `check` constraint. So (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/s1PiGUAE))

```
create table manager(
  id serial primary key,
  account_id int references account(id),
  dept_id int references dept(id),
  constraint dept_xor_account check ( num_nulls(account_id,dept_id) = 1);
```